# Why fillna with mode isn't replacing nan values in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, fillna

I am trying to replace the nan values in a dataframe column 'Functional' using `fillna()` function. The issues I am facing are below:

1. I am able to detect the null values using the `isnull()`

`dfcomp[dfcomp['Functional'].isnull()==True]`

[image: search for null values]

2. using above index I searched the actual value

`dfcomp['Functional'][2216]`

[image: value search using the index]

3. but when I try to fill the nan using `fillna()`, nothing happens. Even after running the fillna statement I can rerun the first statement and see the same 2 nan instances.

`dfcomp['Functional']=dfcomp['Functional'].fillna(value=dfcomp['Functional'].mode())`

I have tried both versions btw

`dfcomp['Functional'].fillna(value=dfcomp['Functional'].mode(),inplace=True)`

[image: The fillna()]

4. I also tried using the `replace()` function for this but no luck

`dfcomp['Functional']=dfcomp['Functional'].replace({'nan':dfcomp['Functional'].mode()})`

Is there something wrong with my code? why is `fillna()` not recognizing the `nan` when `isnull()` can do so?
Also, why is the index search showing the value as `nan` but when I try to replace the same value using `replace()` there is no result?

How can I replace the nan values when my `fillna()` is not able to recognize it?

Comment: Hi PVL, welcome to SO. Images are typically discouraged for coding questions where the output could be copy and pasted into a formatted code block. You can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples to see how to make your data more easily available/reproducible.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially the problem is the return type of `dfcomp['Functional'].mode()`
This a single element `pandas.Series` and the `fillna()` expects either a [scalar or a dict/Series/DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) of the same len as the column you are trying to fill.

You need to calculate the mode of the column and then pass the scalar to the `fillna()` method.

```
mode = dfcomp['Functional'].mode().values[0]
dfcomp['Functional'].fillna(value=mode, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Ok let me try that...but for columns with float values i was able to assign mode in the same way.  -->  `       for col in columns:
    if dfcomp[col].isnull().sum()<400:
        **dfcomp[col]=dfcomp[col].fillna(value=dfcomp[col].mode())**
        print(col," " ,dfcomp[col].isnull().sum())
    else:
        print(col, ' ', 'Missing')
        dfcomp[col].fillna(value='Missing',inplace=True)`

Comment: It is hard to tell without actually seeing the data and the implementation, but it looks odd unless the mode dataframe of the float column happens to have the same number of rows as the original df

Answer (score 2):

This is an `Index` alignment problem. [`pd.Series.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) 
**always returns Series** even if only one value is returned. The index of this Series is thus a `RangeIndex` (up to the number of values tied for the mode) and so when you use `.fillna` it tries to align on Index, which mostly doesn't align with your DataFrame.

You want to select the modal **value** so use `.iloc`

```
dfcomp['Functional'] = dfcomp['Functional'].fillna(dfcomp['Functional'].mode().iloc[0])
```

---

#### MCVE

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': np.random.choice([1,2,3,np.NaN], 7)})

df['foo'].mode()
#0    3.0
#dtype: float64

# Nothing gets filled because only the row with Index 0 could possibly
# be filled and it wasn't missing to begin with
df['foo'].fillna(df['foo'].mode())
#0    3.0
#1    NaN
#2    1.0
#3    3.0
#4    3.0
#5    NaN
#6    1.0
#Name: foo, dtype: float64

# This fills the `NaN` with 3 regardless of index
df['foo'].fillna(df['foo'].mode().iloc[0])
#0    3.0
#1    3.0
#2    1.0
#3    3.0
#4    3.0
#5    3.0
#6    1.0
#Name: foo, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to fill NaN values, you can use the following code:

`dfcomp = dfcomp.fillna(value=0)`

**Later update:**

`dfcomp['Functional'] = dfcomp['Functional'].fillna(dfcomp['mode'])`

Comment: He want's to fill with the mode of the column not 0. Plus it looks like he is trying to fillna in only one column not the entire data frame